# Check if timezone has DST

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

at the moment I am trying to detect if a timezone has DST at all and not if DST affects the timezone at the moment.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
function timezoneDoesDST($tzId) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
    return count($tz->getTransitions(time())) > 0;
}
$tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$termin = new DateTime('2017-08-04 12:00:00',$tz);
$mytimezone=array();
foreach(timezone_abbreviations_list() as $abbr => $timezone){
    foreach($timezone as $val){
        if(isset($val['timezone_id'])){
            $found = 0;
            $tz2 = new DateTimeZone($val['timezone_id']);
            $termin->setTimezone($tz2);
            foreach($mytimezone as $mytz)
            {
                if($mytz['time'] == $termin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                {
                    $found = 1;
                    if(timezoneDoesDST($val['timezone_id']))
                    {
                        $found = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if($found == 0)
            {
                $mytimezone[] = array('time' => $termin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'timezone_id' => $val['timezone_id']);
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach($mytimezone as $mytz)
{
    echo $mytz['time'].' - '.$mytz['timezone_id'].'<br />';
}
```

The thing is, I won't to display all different timezones with a different time and timezones which has a DST at all.

But at the moment it displays me all timezones and if I remove this:

```
if(timezoneDoesDST($val['timezone_id']))
{
    $found = 0;
}
```

It just displays me timezones with different time

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to reinvent the date("I") function? https://3v4l.org/WCIV4 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: So what is the desired result? Do you want a list of timezones which use DST?

Comment: @Andreas Tht date("l") functions just returns if DST is currently effecting the time if I am right. But I would like to generate this list all year long with the same results. So the date("l") function is not working for me

Comment: @JanRydrych I would like to display alle timezones with different time and timezone which use DST at all and not just at the moment. So that if anybody does wont to change his timezone, he's able to select a timezone that matches his time and DST.

Comment: If you run it now and save the list you get your all year working list or whatever. Keep in mind date() will take in to account that not all countries switch the same date between DST and not.

Comment: Tom Scott made a good video about timezones a few years ago https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Here is a good list of all DSTs and when and how. http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/g.html

Comment: @ChristopherSmith - pls try to explain us what are you trying to achieve. You have some termin which has the UTC timezone set. Then you want to show the user what time is it in different timezones - am I getting it right? But I don't understand what is the purpose of figuring out the DST here, because the user wants to know the time with DST included - or a I missing something?

Comment: @JanRydrych The user is able to select his timezone. And the "timezone_abbreviations_list()" offers him something like 1800 options. So my idea was to reduce the amount of timezones that are displayed to a minimum but with all the different times and DST.

Comment: Why would anyone choose a different timezone than the one they are in? I just don't understand the reason for this question. It's like making square car tires, just in case someone want square tires on their car.

Comment: @Andreas they can choose their timezone when they register to the website. If somebody from America registers he can select his timezone and somebody from Australia can select his timezone.

Comment: @ChristopherSmith - Your premise is flawed.  DST occurs differently all over the world.  Did you know in Morocco they have *four* transitions instead of the normal two?  Did you know that some countries *used* to have DST and don't anymore, or didn't and now do, or planned not to and then did?  Or went from standard/daylight time to "permanent daylight time", thus making a new standard time? Or just changed their standard time? Simplifying a time zone list is a difficult thing to get right.  You can't just ask for an offset and DST yes/no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have updated my code a bit to reduce the amount of selected timezones if anybody needs this:

```
    function timezoneDoesDST($tzId) {
        $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);
        return count($tz->getTransitions(time())) > 0;
    }
    $tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $termin = new DateTime('2017-08-04 12:00:00',$tz);
    $mytimezone=array();
    $y = 0;
    foreach(timezone_abbreviations_list() as $abbr => $timezone){

        foreach($timezone as $val){
            if(isset($val['timezone_id'])){
                $y++;
                $found = 0;
                $found2 = 0;
                $tz2 = new DateTimeZone($val['timezone_id']);
                $termin->setTimezone($tz2);
                foreach($mytimezone as $mytz)
                {
                    if($mytz['time'] == $termin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                    {
                        $found = 1;
                    }
                    if(timezoneDoesDST($val['timezone_id']))
                    {
                        if($mytz['time'] == $termin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') and $mytz['timezone_id'] != $val['timezone_id'] and $mytz['DST'] == 0)
                        {
                            $found2 = 1;
                            $found = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($found == 0)
                {
                    $mytimezone[] = array('time' => $termin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'timezone_id' => $val['timezone_id'],'DST' => $found2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $mylist = count($mytimezone);
    echo $mylist.' - '.$y.'<br /><br />';
    foreach($mytimezone as $mytz)
    {
        echo $mytz['time'].' - '.$mytz['DST'].' - '.$mytz['timezone_id'].'<br />';
    }
```

This reduces it from about 1500 to 68 different timezones with and without DST.

Cheers and thanks to all.

Comment: I figured out, that the first code I posted showed me all timezone with and without DST with an amount of 1500. That was already correct (I did not noticed that). Now I have removed the duplicated timezones with the same time and the same DST. So it is just 68 now.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution? It generates list of timezones/cities and times calculated from the initial `$mytime` according to actual timezone with respect if the DST is now active or not. I think you don't have to bother with DST (IMHO the user don't care, he wants to know the time for his timezone...)

```
$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);

$mytz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$mytermin = new DateTime('2017-08-04 12:00:00',$mytz);

foreach($tzlist as $tzStr){
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzStr);
    $mytermin->setTimezone($tz);
    echo $mytermin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').' - '.$tzStr.'<br />';
}
```